# Equivalent for HAProxy's option forwardfor/close in Pound

Tags: haproxy, pound

I'm switching from HAProxy to Pound and I need to know if there is an equivalent of

```
option forwardfor
option httpclose
```

in Pound.

BTW, I'm already using the

```
HeadRemove "X-Forwarded-For"
```

in Pound.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Pound does this by default. From http://www.apsis.ch/pound/

> As a general rule, Pound passes all headers as they arrive from the client browser to the back-end server(s). There are two exceptions to this rule: Pound may add information about the SSL client certificate (as described below), and it will add an X-Forwarded-For header. The general format is:

```
    X-Forwarded-for: client-IP-address
```

My problem was that the application (OpenStack) wasn't using the X-Forwarded-for header by default. I set

`--use_forwarded_for=True`

and problem solved.